# warning: URI.escape is obsolete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I'm trying to get Oauth2 access from quickbooks but I'm getting this warning on command promt from rails server and nothing happens server just keeps loading the same warning;

[image]

Here's the line that gives error (located in the gem);

```
    def escape(value)
      URI::escape(value.to_s, OAuth::RESERVED_CHARACTERS)
    rescue ArgumentError
      URI::escape(value.to_s.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8), OAuth::RESERVED_CHARACTERS)
    end
```

I looked at other complains about this error and I tried to replace `URI::escape()` commands with `CGI::escape()` but then I got this error;

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this error and find an alternative that works?
My Ruby version: `ruby 2.7.2p137`
My Rails Version: `Rails 6.1.4`
Thank you.

Comment: Your oauth gem version is from 2012 (Ruby 1.9 era). Updating the oauth gem to a more recent version should fix the issue.

Comment: I can't find a gem called "oauth" my gemfile is like this; `gem 'oauth-plugin'
gem 'quickbooks-ruby', github: 'ruckus/quickbooks-ruby'
gem 'oauth2'
gem 'roxml'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'intuit-oauth'
gem 'qbo_api'`  And I tired running bundle install and bundle update as well.

Comment: It's probably a dependency from another gem in which case you'll only find it in your `Gemfile.lock`. However, you can update it nonetheless via `bundle update oauth`. If that doesn't work, try to update the gem that depends on it.

Comment: Tried running `bundle update oauth` it returned; Bundler attempted to update oauth but its version stayed the same. Could this gem abandoned by any chance?

Comment: It doesn't look abandoned – its [current version](https://rubygems.org/gems/oauth) is 0.5.6 from April 02, 2021. However, [oauth-plugin](https://rubygems.org/gems/oauth-plugin) seems to be a bit dated: the last release is from 2013 which limits _oauth_ to `0.4.x`. You might have to look for a replacement.

Comment: I am following a tutorial by minimul. Trying to integrate my ruby on rails app to Quickbooks online via V3 API. I tried following the tutorial but it's very outdated and has issues. I'm checking literally every source that I can find but I don't fully understand what to do since they are less explaining and I'm a newbie. I don't know which gem that I should replace it with. I'm afraid that it could mess my app.

Comment: If you want / have to keep the gem(s), you can always take a look at the current source of [`lib/oauth/helper.rb`](https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth-ruby/blob/master/lib/oauth/helper.rb) and create a monkey-patch based on it. Seems like replacing `URI::escape` with `URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.escape` does the trick. However, authentication is a sensitive topic and running outdated libraries is risky. You should try to stay up-to-date.

Comment: When I try the monkeypatch I get `EOFError in VendorsController#authenticate
end of file reached` error on; `/home/kvothe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:225:in `rbuf_fill'` I think we can't fix it by monkeypatching.

Comment: It looks like Intuit has a Ruby SDK which can interact with Quickbooks, see here https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/sdks-and-samples-collections/ruby/oauth-ruby-client

Comment: Thanks @maxpleaner but I've already checked this. And I couldn't walkthrough all steps. First of all I don't know where to put those codes into an initializer? My controller? If so under which method etc. I don't know what is "The Right Enviorment" and don't know how to set up an enviorment. I'm not sure which variables to replace and which to leave alone. It's just like a guessing game for me and I guess wrong frequently not getting any close.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is a working implementation of `URI.escape`, you could re-implement it yourself:

```
# config/initializers/uri.rb

module URI
  def self.escape(*args)
    DEFAULT_PARSER.escape(*args)
  end
end
```

This will effectively remove the warning and delegate the `escape` call to the default parser, which also works in Ruby 3.

Note that this is just a quick patch to silence the warning. In the long run, you should find a replacement for the outdated gem(s).

Comment: When I try this the warning is silenced but server just keeps on loading without an error and command prompt is stable. AndI can not stop the server with ctrl+c. I can stop it with ctrl+z.

Comment: @Kvothe28 does the server run without that patch?

Comment: When I click  "Connect to Quickbooks" button, I'm getting an error or just like in the question Uri.escape warnings.

Comment: @Kvothe28 a warning is not an error. A warning is just a message and the programs continues (like in your first screenshot). An error / exception causes your process / thread to terminate (like in your second screenshot). If you get an error even without the patch, then the patch clearly isn't causing it. Neither does the deprecation warning. If you can't get the project running with Ruby 2.7 you might want to try an older version of Ruby (maybe even 1.9.3). Once it runs follow the [Upgrading Ruby on Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) guide to upgrade it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```rb
# config/initializers/uri.rb
module URI
  def self.escape url
    URI::Parser.new.escape url
  end
end
```